# Let R = $\{ (n+4,n) \mid n \in \Bbb Z^+\}$, Find $R^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

I found that this relation is not transitive, does this mean that $R^2$ does not exists?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Even non-transitive relations have "squares" and higher powers. For example the relation $S$ on the set of all people (living or dead), defined by "is child of" is not transitive, but $S$ contains (me, my-father), (my-father, my-grandfather-Charles) and (my-mother, my-grandfather-Louis). Because of this, $S^2$ contains (me, my-grandfather-Charles) and (me, my-grandfather-Louis).

Comment: I see, but what would you say that in this case, $R^2$ would be? since n+4 and n always have a difference of 4, but if you have something like (x, z) and (z, y) then (x,y) would always have a bigger difference than 4

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. And what would that larger difference actually be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation $R$ on the set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is given by
$$
R \colon= \left\{ \, (n+4, n) \colon n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \, \right\}.
$$
This $R$ can also be written as
$$
R = \big\{ \, (5,  1), (6, 2), (7, 3), (8, 4),   \ldots \big\}
$$
Thus the relation $R^2 \colon= R\circ R$ is given by
$$
R^2 \colon= \left\{ \, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \colon \exists \, c \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mbox{ for which } (a, c) \in R, (c, b) \in R \, \right\}.
$$
That is,
$$
\begin{align}
R^2 &= \left\{ \, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+ \colon \exists \, c \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mbox{ for which } c+4 = a, b+4 = c \, \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \colon \exists \, c \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mbox{ for which } a-4 = c = b+4 \, \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \colon a-4 = b+4 \, \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \colon a = b+8 \, \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \, (b+8, b) \colon b\in \mathbb{Z}^+ \, \right\}.
\end{align}
$$

Using the same logic, we can show that, for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$
R^k = \left\{ \, (b+4k, b) \colon b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \, \right\}.
$$

And, then
$$
R^* = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R^k.
$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For $n,m\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ we have:$$nRm\iff n=m+4$$

Then by *definition* of $R^2$ for $n,m\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ we have: $$nR^2m\iff n=k+4\text{ and }k=m+4\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb Z^{+}$$

This shows immediately that: $$nR^2m\implies n=m+8$$

Conversely if $n,m\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ with $n=m+8$ then $k:=m+4\in\mathbb Z^+$ and this with $n=k+4$.

So we conclude that: $$nR^2m\iff n=m+8$$

Or equivalently that:$$R^2=\{(n+8,n)\mid n\in\mathbb Z^+\}$$